# Existence of Jungian archetypes

Tags: psychology, psychoanalysis, reason

I can't seem to make sense of any of the summary definitions of an archetype according to Jung.

Has a consise, consistent definition been given anywhere?

Comment: It might make more sense to ask this on the psychology SE unless that didn't get the results you were looking for.  https://psychology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This may help, hope so :

> The second use of archetype comes from the analytical psychology of C.
>   G. Jung (1875-1961) and his theories of the "collective unconscious."5 For
>   Jung, an individual has not only the ego and personal unconscious that
>   Sigmund Freud demonstrated, but also a "collective" unconscious. The
>   "collective" unconscious contains memories, imprints, and modes of
>   human development and behavior conditioned by mankind's entire history. Jung argues that this collective unconscious manifests itself in the
>   affairs of individuals by means of primordial images or patterns of psychic
>   activities, which he calls "archetypes." Among the most important
>   archetypes are God; the savior-redeemer; the hero; the mother; the father;
>   the miraculous child; the shadow; the old wise man; the anima and the
>   animus; and the self. According to Jung, an archetype is a psychic
>   phenomenon, not a visible, tangible thing. Indeed, no one has ever directly
>   confronted an archetype, since archetypal psychic activity introduces into
>   human life only the traces, or "footprints," of the archetype. In Jungian
>   psychology, archetypes manifest themselves by means of concrete,
>   sensuously apprehensible* forms, which he calls "images of the archetypes."
>   Such images are frequently revealed in dreams, folklore, fairy tales, myths,
>   art, literature, and even in popular culture. Strange beasts and myth characters in dreams, heroes and heroines in tales and stories, and figures
>   such as Superman, Tarzan, and Dirty Harry in popular culture are tangible
>   instances of what Jung terms manifest images of archetypal activity.
>
> If we say, for example, "The motion-picture character Shane is the
>   archetype of the hero," then we are probably using the term in its Jungian
>   context. Similarly, if we say, "In World War II Winston Churchill
>   awakened in Englishmen the image of the hero as warrior-crusader," we are
>   likely invoking Jung's theory of archetypes. If, however, we say, "In World
>   War II Winston Churchill became the archetype of the wartime prime
>   minister," we are using tthe term to denote model or prototype.

Source : Joseph K. Davis, 'IMAGE, SYMBOL, AND ARCHETYPE: DEFINITIONS AND USES', Interpretations, Vol. 16, No. 1 (FALL 1985), pp. 28-29.

['Sensuously apprehensible' just means perceptible by or through the senses.]